# Install direct downloaded IOS 6.0.1

Tags: itunes, ios

I've downloaded IOS 6.0.1 from direct link(not using iTunes). My download can't complete in iTunes as my internet disconnects before completion. So, guys, can anybody help me how can I install downloaded IOS on my iPhone 4S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## iOS Updates Using a Downloaded IPSW File

*Note that `.ipsw` files are specific to the device (i.e. the iPhone 4 GSM is distinct from the iPhone 4 CDMA). Make sure you download the correct one.*

1. Plug your iPhone into your computer with the USB cable (Wi-Fi won't work for this).
2. Open the iPhone device page in iTunes (either from the sidebar in iTunes 10, or the *Devices* button in iTunes 11).
3. While holding down option (or shift in Windows), click the **Restore** button. You should get an open file dialog.
4. Select the `.ipsw` file you downloaded, and click **OK**. Your iPhone should start to update normally.

Comment: He actually can't install iOS 6 on iPhone 4S since isn't signed anymore by apple.

Answer (score 1):

This method doesn't work since Itunes no matter what  needs to check the version of the iOS with the update server, in other words you would need internet to install it, if the version is older the server will reject it and you need to install directly from their servers

Answer (score 0):

While the iPhone is plugged in, go to the devices tab. Hold the (left) SHIFT key and click update. Go to the directory of the iOS, and enjoy :)